# Does Defining Resources In XML Cause Parsing Overhead?

Tags: java, android, xml, view

Does The Parsing Of XML Resource File In Android Happen During Runtime? 
And If There Is Any Parsing Overhead, Does Writing Views Programatically Eliminates It?
If resources are created in a separate .java file and then loaded, will they consume more memory than defining them in XML?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html. check the docs

Comment: Memory is absolutely negligible here. The memory used while the xml is parsed should also become available once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the XML Resource files (Layouts, Drawables, etc.) are parsed during runtime.  However the amount of overhead this creates is quite small.  As far as the amount of memory consumed goes, since the XML files are parsed in to source (optimized versions of what you would write) they will take up approximately the same amount of RAM as a separate .java file would.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

[At compile time](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html), XML resources are compiled to a binary XML format. These binary XML files are then parsed (decoded) at runtime on device, but this is faster than parsing the original textual XML.

Theoretically, generating view hierarchies in code is faster than inflating a binary XML. In practice the difference is often negligible. *Maintaining* view hierarchies in code rather than XML is much more expensive in terms of developer time.

Memory consumption differences are likely not significant either.